# Integrate powerbi dataset back into report

Tags: powerbi

I have a report which uses a powerbi dataset as as a datasource. I would like to transfer all the data loading and transformations to the report so that I only need a single file and a database-connection but preferably i would not rebuild all transformations and reassign the data in the graphics, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Build your report into the existing one that hosts the dataset. Any other option will not satisfy your requirement to have one file and one database connection.

Comment: Is there a way to copy report pages from the report to the dataset file or another way to reconstruct the report without actually building it again?

Comment: Should be possible to create a new page in the dataset report, select all visuals in one page of the new report, copy all of it and paste it into the new page. Make sure canvas dimensions are 1:1.